# Getting regular datetime format instead of epoch time when converting from string to datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, string, datetime, epoch

I have string type dates in a column that has the following format: `August 14, 2020`. I would like to convert it into a datetime object with the usual datetime format, but using the code below gives me epoch time:

```
df.loc[mask, 'date_added'] = df.loc[mask,'date_added'].apply(lambda x : pd.to_datetime(x))
```

I know you can use `.fromtimestamp()` but is there an option within `.to_datetime()` to get a datetime object and format? I think using `.fromtimestamp()` will also be hard to incorporate into one lambda function. I also tried adding `.to_period()` to the lambda function, which resulted in the correct format but caused problems down the line when plotting with seaborn.

Is there a way to get it into a regular datetime format when converting string to datetime?

Example Data:

```
    show_id     date_added
0   s1     August 14, 2020
1   s2    December 23, 2016
2   s3    December 20, 2018
3   s4    November 16, 2017
```

df code for example data:

```
pd.DataFrame(([(0, 's1', 'August 14, 2020'), (1, 's2', 'December 23, 2016'),
           (2, 's3', 'December 20, 2018'), (3, 's4', 'November 16, 2017')]), columns=['index', 'id', 'date_added'])
```

Comment: you can pass a series to `pd.to_datetime`. That said, if you only update a part of the column with `.loc[mask,]`, the column still have object dtype.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an "inplace = True" option for pd.to_datetime. Is there a way to do this without a mask?

Comment: What is `mask`? By the way, Pandas is pretty smart, you can just do `pd.to_datetime(df['date_added'])`.

Comment: Besides, datetime dtype has no *format*, as datetime as a string has. Also, what do you mean by "epoch format"?

Comment: @Quang Hoang A mask is a filter with Panda boolean operators, ie `not_null = df['date_added'].isnull() == False` in this case. It's used to change certain part of the original df using .loc. And `pd.to_datetime(df['date_added'])` seems to work, but when I extract the year after using it to convert the column, it gives me a decimal year which creates problems further down the line. Do you know why that is?

Comment: @MrFuppes Epoch time is in the number of seconds that have elapsed since the Unix epoch (1/1/1970) and looks like this: `1347517370`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do `df['date_added']=df['date_added'].astype('datetime')`

Comment: Would this be a separate line after the above code (lambda function)?

Comment: it gets rid of the need for that line altogether, it just parses the whole column into datetime.